# Unable to Create New Yahoo Application recently

Tags: yahoo-oauth

I wanted to create a new OAuth API key for my application and i am not able to do so from yesterday. I am getting the error:

> Application Create failed. Database error creating first Version for
>   new App:

Also I am also not able to see my existing API details. Has anyone is experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Similar problem here! And [their support](https://developer.yahoo.com/support/oauth/) points here!! I Can't access this URL: https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/

Comment: It was broken for me last week too but the site appears to be up after the weekend. Did someone at Yahoo hear us?